# Tomcate welcome page is not showing after installation of jasperserver on linux

Tags: apache, jasperserver

I have install jasperserver on linux .Tomcate server is running and their is no error during installation but when i run this on browser its not showing me welcome page. http://hostname:8080/jasperserver. In catalina.out file this INFO is showing and no error in log files.

> The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found.

Comment: This is not a solution nor a simple answer to your question but a comment about the APR message : if APR library is not found in binary format during Tomcat then a Java version is used as workaround. Functionalities are the same but execution time is worth than with a binary lib. APR can be compiled on your system (it's a simple command line step) or installed if your OS is packaged based (like Debian, Ubuntu, RedHat, ...).

Comment: In all case APR library missing is not related to Tomcat/Jasper welcome page missing. To solve your problem, have a look to server.xml configuration file and into <tomcat_home>/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml file.

Comment: What do i check in web.xml file? Please guide me

Comment: is this can be version compatiblity issue betwwen linux and jasperser?